# Assigning variable in javascript error returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I don't know if this is a glitch or a mistake that I made. But I use `console.log(record)` this is the result

```
accountRateId: 6
effectiveEndDate: "2019-09-30T00:00:00"
effectiveStartDate: "2019-09-01T00:00:00"
rate: 100
```

I have this code to assign the variables

```
let rate = record.rate;
let effectiveStartDate = record.effectiveStartDate;
let effectiveEndDate = record.effectiveEndDate;
console.log(rate);
```

but console.log(rate) returns undefined. Can anyone help me with this?

Update:
This is the code from the api

```
[Authorize("ADMIN")]
[HttpGet("Update/{id}")]
public IActionResult GetUpdate([FromQuery]QueryPagingParametersForNotes inParameters, int id)
{
     List<object> rateList = new List<object>();

     var rateListQueryResults = Database.AccountRates.Where(rate => rate.AccountRateId == id);
     foreach (var oneRate in rateListQueryResults)
     {
     rateList.Add(new
             {
             accountRateId = oneRate.AccountRateId,
             rate = oneRate.RatePerHour,
             effectiveStartDate = oneRate.EffectiveStartDate,
             effectiveEndDate = oneRate.EffectiveEndDate,
             });
      }
     return new JsonResult(rateList);
}
```

This is the the code in javascript

```
 $.ajax({
       method: 'GET',
       url: '/API/AccountRates/Update/' + inId
       }).done(function (data) {
             let record = data;
             console.log(record);
             let rate = record.rate;
             let effectiveStartDate = record.effectiveStartDate;
             let effectiveEndDate = record.effectiveEndDate;
             console.log(rate);
             console.log(effectiveStartDate);
                    //Populate the respective input controls with the lesson details.
             $('#rateInput').val(rate);
             $('#startDateInput').val(effectiveStartDate);
             $('#endDateInput').val(effectiveEndDate);

})
```

Comment: where are you getting the `record` variable from?

Comment: But there is no `rate` property in your `record` object. `let rate = record.rate;`

Comment: `record.rate` is defined or not?

Comment: I think it is defined as it returns rate: 100 in console.log(record)

Comment: can you post the original json Format?

Comment: Show the exact syntax of `record`, including all the bracers and commas or a JSON.stringified() version. Either the structure is not as you say, or there's code changing your variables, since it is not possible that `rate:100` is a property of record, and still have `let rate = record.rate` not work.

Comment: the record variable is assigned as data from a httpget method the data is from my database

Comment: Show, don't tell. One of the lines in your code is going to be in the wrong position or your record is not what you think it is. Or something silly like record still being a json string, or a typo in one of the names. You do not have errors right?

Comment: ```
0: {accountRateId: 6, rate: 100, effectiveStartDate: "2019-09-01T00:00...
```
It cuts off and has...
I am sorry but I am not sure how to get the

Comment: Copy paste the code. We're not going to retype all your code to test it if you post a screenshot. But at first look, either data or record is an array instead of an object, explaining the issue.

Comment: Add `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` or `console.log(JSON.stringify(record));` to your code. Anyways, either `record[0].rate` or `data[0].rate` should work.

Comment: I have posted the code ill try adding the console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

Comment: Yeah, your JSON response string probably looks like this: `[{"accountRateId:6,"rate":100,"effectiveStartDate":"2019","effectiveEndDate:"2019"}]`. So your response is an Array, wrapping one object because your id should be unique. So the solution is `let rate = record[0].rate;`. If that throws an error, you haven't parsed the JSON string yet and should add the correct responseType to your jquery ajax() call.

Comment: Record looks like an array

Comment: N.B. If the intention is only ever to return one record from the query, why did you create a list in the C#? Just return a single object from the server instead of a list, and then you won't have to amend anything in the JavaScript.